# GPU Jank when generate endless 2D terrain

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm making a runner game which has the infinity mode.
So, I got to generate a terrain every 1s approximately.
It has some lag with my LG Q9 One, I checked the performance and it appeared that there's some problem with Raster thread.

[image: Lag in raster thread 1]

I tried the game on Samsung Galaxy Note 10 which has better gpu and it shows less janks(but it has janks anyway).

I adds my code here. Any better way to enhance the performance?

```
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  final Grid grid = Grid();
  final EndlessMap endlessMap = EndlessMap();
  final Runner runner = Runner();

  double speed = 100.0;

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() {
    add(grid);
    add(endlessMap);
    add(runner);
    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

/// Camera follows the runner.
class Runner extends PositionComponent with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() {
    gameRef.camera.followComponent(this);
    return super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    x += gameRef.speed * dt;
    super.update(dt);
  }
}

/// Set the size of tile and grid
class Grid extends Component with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  late int rows = 10;
  late int columns;
  late int mapColumns;
  late double tileSize;

  @override
  void onGameResize(Vector2 size) {
    tileSize = (size.y / rows).floorToDouble();
    columns = (size.x / tileSize).ceil();
    mapColumns = columns + 2;
    super.onGameResize(size);
  }
}

/// Generate terrains endlessly
class EndlessMap extends PositionComponent with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  late final Sprite terrainSprite;
  late final List<SpriteComponent> terrainSpritePool;

  int firstTerrainIndex = 0;

  // Init terrain sprite
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    terrainSprite = Sprite(
      await Flame.images.load('terrains.png'),
      srcPosition: Vector2(4.0, 0.0),
      srcSize: Vector2(32.0, 32.0 * 10),
    );

    terrainSpritePool = List.generate(
      gameRef.grid.mapColumns,
      (index) => SpriteComponent(sprite: terrainSprite),
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < terrainSpritePool.length; i++) {
      terrainSpritePool[i].size.x = gameRef.grid.tileSize;
      terrainSpritePool[i].position = Vector2(
        i * gameRef.grid.tileSize,
        gameRef.grid.tileSize,
      );
      add(terrainSpritePool[i]);
    }

    return super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    final dx = gameRef.speed * dt;
    final lastTerrainIndex = firstTerrainIndex == 0
        ? terrainSpritePool.length - 1
        : firstTerrainIndex - 1;

    // When the first terrain is behind the camera,
    if (terrainSpritePool[firstTerrainIndex].position.x +
            gameRef.grid.tileSize <=
        gameRef.camera.position.x + dx) {
      // Move the first terrain to the end
      terrainSpritePool[firstTerrainIndex].size.x = gameRef.grid.tileSize;
      terrainSpritePool[firstTerrainIndex].position = Vector2(
        terrainSpritePool[lastTerrainIndex].position.x + gameRef.grid.tileSize,
        gameRef.grid.tileSize,
      );

      firstTerrainIndex = (firstTerrainIndex + 1) % terrainSpritePool.length;
    }

    super.update(dx);
  }
}
```

You can find a whole code in [github](https://github.com/swippylab/flutter_flame_endless_map_2d).

2022.09.12. ----------------

It seems like the issue with that my phone(LG Q9 One) has a bad gpu to run it normally. I removed all the codes except moving the camera, it still shows janks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce the shader compilation and run your animations smoothly, there is an article in the official [flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/shader) website explaining about a solution
Hope this helps

Comment: Oh.. I forgot the very important condition... It generates terrains randomly. So I'm not sure that SkSL warmup would work. But I'll try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to not create new objects in the update method.
So when you are doing:

```dart
terrainSpritePool[firstTerrainIndex].position = Vector2(
  terrainSpritePool[lastTerrainIndex].position.x + gameRef.grid.tileSize,
  gameRef.grid.tileSize,
);
```

Since the `SpriteComponent` already has a `Vector2` you can re-use it like this:

```dart
terrainSpritePool[firstTerrainIndex].position.setValues(
  terrainSpritePool[lastTerrainIndex].position.x + gameRef.grid.tileSize,
  gameRef.grid.tileSize,
);
```

Comment: Oh. It's very good idea.I got to check all the codes in update() to optimize.